# Incompatible pointer types initializing 'NSMutableDictionary *' with an expression of type 'NSDictionary *'

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

My warning in Xcode :

```
Incompatible pointer types initializing 'NSMutableDictionary *' with an expression of type 'NSDictionary *'
```

For this code :

```
NSMutableDictionary* dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                 [NSNumber numberWithLongLong:byteCount],@"bytes",
                                 [NSNumber numberWithLong:fileCount],@"files",nil];
    [dict writeToFile:countsPath atomically:YES];
```

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: yeah can't be any clearer than that: `NSMutableDictionary* dict = [NSDictionary`... different type

Comment: It's telling you exactly what's happening -- your l-value is an NSMutableDictionary, but you're initializing it with a NSDictionary -- inconsistent types.

Comment: Since all you are doing is writing the dictionary, change `dict` to of type `NSDictionary`.

Comment: HJMOFileCache problem. Nicely done and a good question. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

change this word:

NSMutableDictionary

to

NSDictionary

and fix all errors it will cause

Comment: ...Or vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot initialize an `NSMutableDictionary` to be `[NSDictionary ....` You can, however, assign an `NSMutableDictionary` to an `NSDictionary` after they have been created and initialized. The reason is because `NSMutableDictionary` is a subclass of `NSDictionary`, so it can be assigned that way, but not the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

I also made a mistake like this:

```
  NSMutableDictionary *data = @{ @"value" : value, @"contentArray" : arrayData };
```

Its very tempting to make this problem. :D

Answer (score 0):

NSMutableDictionary is a subclass of NSDictionary and you are trying the vice-versa.